# How to delete item by index from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

For dictionaries, this works:

```
del dict["Key"][index]
```

But for this code, it doesn't.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv")
gr=df.groupby("continent")

#returns dict
continents=gr.groups

#acces to value by index in dictionary "continents"
print(continents["Asia"][2]) #working

del continents["Asia"][2] #Not working...
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/1/Documents/Practica/practice.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1/Documents/Practica/practice.py", line 13, in <module>
    del continents["Asia"][2] 
AttributeError: __delitem__
13
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Wow. This is legitimately unexpected and I'm surprised I've never seen it before.

Comment: Works fine in Python 3 https://rextester.com/MCO7338

Comment: I can’t reproduce this, it works fine.

Comment: Works for me in both python 2.7.17 and 3.6.9.  Where does it not work?

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I edit, please help why isn't work... if is dictionary...

Comment: You have a dict of `pandas.Int64Index` objects, **not lists**. The issue isn't the `dict`. The issue is that pandas index objects are immutable, you cannot mutate them. In any case, I've voted to re-open, and tagged this with pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
continents.drop(2, inplace=True)
```

Let me know if this works for you or not

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What about a simple `dic["A"].pop(0)`?